# Laravel Request::Intended goes to home

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm making this authentication filter, but when it gets to the `Reguest::intended()` it just throws me back to the homepage.

Example:

Tries to access `forum.dev/admin` -> Forces me to login -> Password and username is correct -> Goes back to `forum.dev/` where it should go to `forum.dev/admin`

How do I fix this?

```
Route::filter('auth.role', function()
{

    // Get Current logged in user
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Check if the user is logged in
    if( Auth::check() && $user->role >= 2 ) 
    {
        // User is admin, let him through!
        return Redirect::intended();
    }
    else
    {   
        // User is not logged in
        return Redirect::to('/login')->withErrors("You need to be logged in or admin!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about below? Replace `Redirec::to` with `Redirect::guest` on unauthenticated user. `Redirect::guest` saves intended url in session and Redirect::intended can use it later.

```
Route::filter('auth.role', function()
{
    // Get Current logged in user
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Check if the user is logged in
    if( Auth::check() && $user->role >= 2 ) 
    {
        // User is admin, let him through!
        return Redirect::intended();
    }
    else
    {   
        // User is not logged in
        return Redirect::guest('/login')->withErrors("You need to be logged in or admin!");
    }
});
```

Comment: the `return Redirect::guest` did the trick! and I had to remove the `return Redirect::intended();` as I already did that in the login process. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect::intended()` checks the session for an intended route, then redirects to that if it exists, otherwise redirect to a fallback url.

Try the following:

```
Route::filter('auth.role', function()
{

    // Get Current logged in user
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Check if the user is logged in
    if( Auth::check() && $user->role >= 2 ) 
    {
        // User is admin, let him through!
        return Redirect::intended('/'); // not required, but best practice to use a fallback URL
    }
    else
    {   

        if ( ! Session::has('url.intended')) {

             Session::flash('url.intended', URL::current());
        }
        // User is not logged in
        return Redirect::to('/login')->withErrors("You need to be logged in or admin!");
    }
});
```

As far as i know, `Auth::check()` by default do not keep the intended URL into the session. however,  `Auth::guest()` automatically put the intended URL into the session.

Comment: Didn't work, the browser goes into a continuous loop.